# What's the callback function for every object registered to boost io_service?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

We register one object to io_service by using a constructor:

```
boost::asio::io_service io;
boost::asio::deadline_timer t(io, boost::posix_time::seconds(5));
```

and how to specify the callback function for this object? In the boost io_service example, the callback function is:

```
t.async_wait(print);
```

But can we specify other or multiple callback functions for t? How does io_service knows which is the right callback function?

Comment: I'm afraid the word "callback" misleads you. Actually, it's a *completion handler* for the asynchronous operation. So you pass such a handler for every async operation, and Asio guarantees to invoke this handler, when the operation gets completed (successfully or not).

Comment: Thanks and what do you mean by when the operation gets completed? What's the operation here mean?

Comment: `async_wait` is the asynchronous operation; it gets completed when the timeout expires or an error occurs (eg. the operation is cancelled).

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the timer.3 and following examples in boost::asio, you'll see the use of boost::bind and the placeholders.  That is how you bind a callback function.  Only one callback function per async_wait.

Comment: Why the callback function has to be put inside the async_wait() function?

Comment: If you take a look at the documentation for the deadline_timer, you will see the documentation for the async_wait method.  The method takes as a parameter, the function to be called at the end of the wait.